# Reliably detecting HTML button release on multiple platforms

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I want to do something that would seem simple: turn a div green while the div is clicked or touched. (That is, essentially, a button that can be pressed for an arbitrary number of seconds).

I *almost* have it working in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/lrodgi/66gramjh/

What I am doing (which *almost* works), is simply to listen for the mouseup and touchend events for release:

```
jbtn.on('mousedown touchstart', function(event) {
    onPressed();
});

$(document).on('mouseup touchend', function() {
    onReleased();
});
```

This works fine on computers, but in mobile browsers the context menu that appears after holding for a while breaks it. Therefore, I prevent that menu from appearing through:

```
function onContextMenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}

jbtn.on('contextmenu', onContextMenu);
```

With these, it seems to work fine in all desktop browsers and in mobile Chrome. However, it still does not work properly in Firefox Mobile.

In Firefox mobile, when I hold the div pressed for a few seconds, no menu appears, but a 'touchcancel' event is raised. Not a touchend or a mouseup. So the div is never released.

Any idea for it to work perfectly?

I wouldn't mind using javascript libraries. In fact, I've tried jQuery Mobile's vmouseup and vmousedown events, with no success (the touchcancel that occurs after a few seconds also prevents the vmouseup from raising).

Answer (score 0):

How about the CSS [pseudo selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements) `:active` and `:focus`?

```
#btn {
  background-color: green;
}
#btn:active, #btn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
.all {
  // Just in case.
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  user-select: none;
  touch-callout: none;
}

#btn {
  background-color: green;
}
#btn:active, #btn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div id="btn" class="released" style="width: 50px; height: 50px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, in mobile Firefox (in a Galaxy S6 Edge at least), it seems to not work properly either. If you long tap the square it remains red even after releasing the tap.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem was that, in Firefox mobile, a 'touchcancel' event was being raised when intercepting the 'contextmenu' event.

I have currently found no way, in Firefox mobile, to prevent the 'contextmenu' from JavaScript and at the same time be able to detect when the actual touch ends ('touchcancel' is raised and then no 'touchend' occurs, even when users are still holding the touch).

However, the workaround I have found is to ensure through CSS that I need no 'contextmenu' prevention by avoiding using the `<img>` tag (which would lead to a save-image contextmenu on long presses), using user-select:none to avoid the copy-paste contextmenu, etc.

Seemingly working snippet:

```js
function onPressed() {
  $("#btn").addClass("pressed");
  $("#btn").removeClass("released");
}

function onReleased() {
  $("#btn").addClass("released");
  $("#btn").removeClass("pressed");
}

var jbtn = $("#btn");

jbtn.on('mousedown touchstart', function(event) {
 onPressed();
});

$(document).on('mouseup touchend', function() {
  onReleased();
});

jbtn.on('mouseup mouseleave touchend', function() {
  onReleased();
});
```

```css
.all {
  // Just in case.
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  user-select: none;
  touch-callout: none;
}

.pressed {
    background-color: red;
}

.released {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all">
  <div id="btn" class="released" style="width: 50px; height: 50px">
  </div>
</div>

<textarea>
  Just testing
</textarea>
```

It is noteworthy that if I required to switch an `<img>` instead of switching background color on a div, this solution would not work as-is. (The save-image dialog would pop up, and the contextmenu event couldn't be used to prevent it).